# Is this temperature normal for i5 cpu?

Tags: cpu

Anyone running a i5 CPU with Ubuntu ?

here's my output of `sensors`:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +53.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +49.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +53.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        3414 RPM
```

I'm not sure if it's beyond standard , I'm running chromium browser only , and `top` shows no process went above 10% CPU usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal temperature.In Intel core i5 2400 Mobile Processers, The temperature should exeed than 100 °C. Check out [this](http://ark.intel.com/products/52224/Intel-Core-i5-2410M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz). Find Package Specification > T JUNCTION shows Threshhold  temperature.

Answer (score 1):

for a laptop cpu that is more than fine, my MacBooks CPU runs hotter than that when idling.

Answer (score 1):

If it is high I have almost the exact same numbers on a i5-2410m

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +47.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +50.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

So I assume it is fine the way it is. My system rarely becomes hot (even when playing video's).

Comment: Did you enabled CPU Frequency scaling ?

Comment: Also I loaded coretemp module , dunno if that matters ..

Comment: I have jupiter installed but when wired to power I have it on maximum performance ;)

Comment: So am I , maximum power , I guess the threshold was 86 C , but the fan was pretty scaring

Comment: fans can be scary indeed :D :D :D